# Is my proof wrong? "Prove that the additive inverse is unique"

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, axioms

"Prove that for each x $\in V$, where $V$ is a vector space, the additive inverse $-x$ is unique."

My proof is as follows;

Let $V$ be a vector space, let $x \in V$. For contradiction, assume the additive inverse $-x$ is not unique. Then, there exists $-x'$ such that

\begin{align*}
x + (-x') = 0 \\
x + (-x) = 0 \\
\end{align*}

We can rearrange this to see

\begin{align*}
x = -(-x') \\
x = -(-x) \\
\Rightarrow -(-x) = -(-x') \\
-x = -x' \\
\end{align*}

Therefore, the additive inverse $-x$ is unique.

In the book and other places I've seen other approaches to this problem, and I'm wondering if this proof is wrong? Other proofs referred to the axioms of vector spaces but I didn't find it necessary. I guess rate my proof would be the point of this question as I'm still uncertain if my proofs are solid.

edit: The axioms referenced are the 8 axioms on Vector Space operations found in "A course in linear algebra" by David Damiano.

Comment: Forgot to include: "assume -x =/ -x'" and this assumption is violated at the end of the proof which is my main argument for the uniqueness.

Comment: The validity of those rearrangements depends on the axioms...

Comment: There's a circularity in your argument as you appear to use $x+y=0\implies y=-x$ (and if you are assuming that, you already have uniqueness).
 Better I think to let the two inverses be $x_1, x_2$ and then write $x_1=x_1+(x_2+x)=x_2+(x_1+x)=x_2$.  That uses commutativity and associativity, but both of those are standard axioms for vector spaces.

Comment: @lulu Why does re-writing y = -x imply uniqueness already? In my assumption $x$ has two additive inverses, $x_1$ and $x_2$, and $x_1 =/ x_2$. Then, $x + x_1 = 0$ and $x + x_2 = 0$. I'm having trouble understanding why re-writing those two in terms of $x$ assumes uniqueness.

Comment: If $x+y=0\implies y=-x$ then we have $x_1=-x=x_2$ so we are done instantly.

Comment: In the spirit of Lulu's first comment, it is unusual to write "Then, there exists $-x'$ such that $x+(-x')=0$." It would make more sense to write "Then, there exists $a\in V$ such that $a \neq -x$ and $x+a=0$."  It is confusing to take this particular $a \in V$ and define it with unnecessary notation that suggests it is the additive inverse of some other vector $x'$.

Comment: The fact that $-(-x)=x$ requires either uniqueness of additive inverses or else a separate proof that $(-1)x = -x$. Also, don't confuse matters with the proof by contradiction. Just assume that $y$ and $z$ are two additive inverses of $x$ and prove that $y=z$.

Comment: I don't know how to upvote comments but @lulu thanks a lot, I understand the circularity in the argument now.

Comment: No worries, glad to have helped.

Comment: @Mithradates : If you have learned something from this discussion perhaps you can view the additive inverse $-x$ as being a function $-x=f(x)$ where $f:V\rightarrow V$, then prove this function $f$ is both injective and surjective. (Your line "Then there is $-x'$" implicitly assumes surjectivity without proof, meaning it assumes every $a\in V$ can be written $a=-v$ for some $v \in V$.).

Comment: @lulu Well I don't see the circularity.  Something is certainly the inverse of it's inverse by definition and the $-$ is that in math language. Then if both inverses equal $x$ then it makes sense they are equal to each other.

Comment: While this can be proved by contradiction your argument doesn't require you to do so. You proved *directly* that $-x = -x'$. Adding contradiction merely clutters the argument.

Comment: @DLGang  As I said, if you are assuming that $x+y=0\implies y=-x$ then you already have uniqueness.  This isn't a standard axiom for vector spaces, however, though of course it does follow from the axioms.  It is, of course, more or less what the OP was being asked to prove, so just assuming it to be true defeats the purpose.

Comment: @lulu , respectfully, That is the definition of inverse. Vector spaces vectors are additive groups and if two elements add to the identity then, by definition, they are inverses of each other. So, it's not circular but it does make the proof require little more.

Comment: Like this $x'=x'+0=x'+x+x^-^1=0+x^-^1=x^-^1$ (sorry can't figure out how to get $-1$ in exponent in mathjax)

Comment: @DLGang  I believe that you can see that exact argument in an earlier comment of mine (your notation is very hard to follow, so I can't be certain, but I expect it is the same argument).  Note that it does not use the assumption that $x+y=0\implies y=-x$.

Comment: @DLGang  to get multiple characters into an exponent, surround them with curly brackets.  Thus x^{-1} renders as $x^{-1}$  (note, however, that that is highly non-standard notation for an additive inverse).

Comment: @Michael That's a very interesting approach, will play around with proving that. In general for linear algebra proofs/axioms/theorems, is there a book that approaches it in a way that does not gloss over these important subtleties? The book i'm currently studying ("A course in linear algebra") is appearing increasingly more vague and non-rigorous.

Comment: @Mithradates Everything important seems to have already been covered but I feel it is worth pointing out that you said you 'forgot to include assume $-x\neq-x'$'. While it is technically fine to do this it is redundant to your argument. It is a good idea to not use proofs by contradiction when direct arguments suffice, in your argument you never use the fact that $-x\neq-x'$ so it isn't needed for your argument. doing this makes your argument messy and non-constructive. As others have pointed out your argument is flawed anyway, I just felt this was worth pointing out given that it came up.

Answer (score 17):

If we have a Vector Space $(V,+)$ with binary composition +, please note that there really is only that, addition. Subtraction is defined as addition with *the* inverse, i.e. $x - y := x + (-y)$. Hence, this definition and way of writing only makes sense if you know already that the inverse is unique.

Hence, the proof of uniquess of the inverse should in my opinion avoid the minus sign altogether, just to optimally have no circularity (i hope that's the correct word). The proof follows just from left cancellation, since V is in particular a Monoid with left cancellation.

Let y $\in$ V. Suppose we have $x, x' \in V$ that satisfy
$$\begin{align*}
y + x = 0\\
y + x' = 0\\
\end{align*}$$
Since $x$ for example is also a left inverse of $y$, we can add it from the left
to get the following:
$$\begin{align*}
x + (y + x) = x\\
x + (y + x') = x\\
\end{align*}$$
Since $V$ is a Monoid, the associative law holds, so we have:
$$\begin{align*}
(x + y) + x = x\\
(x + y) + x' = x\\
\end{align*}$$
Since $x+ y = 0$, the second line yields
$$\begin{align*}
x' = x\\
\end{align*}$$
Just as we wanted. Notice that i actually used the associative law. I believe it is absolutely required for uniqueness of inverses. It is *not* required for uniqueness of identity elements, but i think for the inverses it is, feel free to correct me though.  I know this is a long answer, but i wanted to be as detailed as possible, after all that's what we mathematicians are taught to be, to avoid mistakes. This is my first ever post too, i hope it does not look too bad.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! That's a good answer. I've made an edit to fix a typo for you.  I think you meant "uniqueness of identity elements" in your last paragraph - I'll leave it to you to correct that.

Comment: Both the Q and A left out that x, x’ should be distinct. Perhaps this is obvious, but it makes the proof clearer to me (i.e., that x = x’ is indeed a contradiction).

Comment: @D.BenKnoble It's not a proof by contradiction, though. It's a direct proof that, if $x$ and $x'$ are additive inverses of $y$, then $x=x'$. Which is all we want! It allows us to do things like use the notation $(-y)$ without ambiguity: let's say $y$ is a vector, and you find an additive inverse for $y$, and meanwhile I also find an additive inverse for $y$. You naturally call your result $(-y)$, while I use that name for my result. Which of us is right? Answer: we both are; we have the same result! Indeed, there is only one choice; EVERY additive inverse is equal to yours (and to mine).

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I think we can allow $x$ and $x'$ to be the same or distinct, and then prove that they must be the same.  That avoids wrapping the whole proof inside of "Suppose that $x\neq x'$ ... contradiction".  Omitting that outer wrapper makes the proof clearer to me.

Comment: Ah, agreed. Thanks. I was stuck in the question’s frame by contradiction, which does make this omission